# How to use trace() for function in parent or child environment?

Tags: r

I would like to debug functions from different environment than environmen from which I call `trace()` or `debug()`, but I don't know how to refer to these functions.

```
fun1 <- function() {
  a <-  1
  a
}

fun2 <- function() {
  fun1 <- function(){
    b <- 2
    b
  }
  trace(fun1, browser, where = globalenv())
}

fun1()
fun2()
fun1()
```

Above I have prepared example where in child environment I'm calling `trace()` and want to insert `browser()` into the function defined in parent environment (in my example - global environment, but I'm looking for the solution taking into account any parent environment).

However, in my example `browser()` is inserted into `fun1()` which has `b` as a local variable, so not the function I wanted.

To summarize:

1. How to refer to the function from any parent environment using `trace()`? So also from grandparent, grand grandparent etc.
2. Is it also possible to refer to the function from **child** environment being in parent environment? If yes, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This question was answered by Duncan Murdoch on R-help Mailing List. I'm posting the answer below:*

You are being bitten by normal R scoping.  While `fun2` is executing, as
soon as it executes the `fun1` assignment the name `fun1` is bound to the
local function, so when you use `fun1` in the first argument to `trace()`,
you get that one.  It will ignore then "where" argument because it was
passed a function object.  If you quote the name it will have to do a
lookup and it will use "where".  So write `fun2` like this:

```
fun2 <- function() {
   fun1 <- function(){
     b <- 2
     b
   }
   trace("fun1", browser, where = globalenv())
}
```

*How can I refer to some function from the parent environment (not necessarily defined in the global environment) being in the child environment?*

You could have used `parent.frame()` in place of `globalenv()` if you want a
function that was visible to the caller of fun2.  If you want a function
that was defined with the same environment as fun2, you can usually use
`environment(fun2)`, or `parent.env(environment())`

*Can I refer to some function from the child environment being in the parent environment? I guess not, because of ephemerality?*

Sometimes you can, but not usually.  If `fun2` had returned a value that
referenced the evaluation frame, you would be able to see the "b"
version of fun1 there.  But yours didn't.  This one would:

```
fun2 <- function() {
   fun1 <- function(){
     b <- 2
     b
   }
   trace("fun1", browser, where = globalenv())
   environment()
}
```

Now if you do `e <- fun2()`, you'll set the trace on the global `fun1`, but
`e$fun1` will be the local one.

*Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2021-December/473434.html*